# Does Windows Remote Desktop lock or hide the screen of the remote PC

Tags: windows-7

[image]

Does Windows Remote Desktop lock or hide the screen of the remote PC?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: That actually results in some confusion if the local user has not been sufficiently warned that you are logging in this way. Their screen goes black, and they have to move the mouse or type to get the sign on screen, which then takes control back away from you when they do sign in. I've gone back and forth like this with users before who called for help but apparently wanted to watch what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.

When you connect to a different computer remotely using Microsoft Remote Desktop (mstsc.exe), the host will be locked. Any user working on the computer will thus get a lock screen. When they unlock the computer, a remote connection automatically gets disconnected.

The user behind the computer can then resume the session the remote user was working on, if they use the same username/password combination.